# Automation server can't create object IE(9) - activex with .cab file

Tags: c#, activex

I have created a class library in c# and with the setup file i have created a cab file. Now in the html page inside object written codebase =xyz.cab. every thing goes good. on running the html page it asks for installing the activex control and also installes successfully. But when creating object of the active x, it shows error "Automation server can't create object". After very much googling i am not able to resolve this issue. I have changed the browser setting as suggested by google. The setup file gets installs successfully and also in registry.

```
var activeX = null;
         activeX = new ActiveXObject('Printer');
```

i am struggling with this error since last 7 hours. Any help guys.....

Comment: hey guys please suggest me what should i do..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the error because ActiveX is not properly installed in the system. During creation of ActiveX control make sure that Register property is set to "vsdrpCOM" of the Primary output of set up file.